# os.system() keeps giving me import errors

Tags: python, operating-system

I am using os.system("python game2.py") to run different parts of my code.

Every time I try this it gives me an import error for example "no module named pygame" even though when I game2 itself, it works fine.

What can I do?

Comment: Why are you using `os.system` for this? Just do `import game2`. `os.system` will only "work" for extremely simple cases. That command spawns a new interpreter for every file, which would eventually cause issues, on top of being inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like said in other answers there is no need to run os.system() if you want to import the code. You can instead use the `import` function in python.

However I think the reason for the error with the command may be to do with what happens to the directories you are in when you run that command.

When you run the command the directory you are in is the same directory as the code is being run from. Then when you run the `game2.py` code and it tries to `import pygame` the reason it can't find it is because it is only looking the cwd (current working directory) as it normally would however the cwd could be different in the `os.system()` command.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you shouldn't even do that for code in different files, you can just do `import game2` and then run the functions inside of it. As an example, `game2.RunGame()`, If you have a function called that, of course this is just an example

Comment: I am trying this but it is saying "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'RunGame'" Even though I created a function called "RunGame" in the code

Comment: RunGame is just an example, for example, if you had a function
`def YourFunctionName():
     print("hello world")
`